# How to convert fabric.js Object to SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs

I know it's possible to convert the whole cavas to SVG. But is it possible to convert separate objects like `Path`, `Line`, `Rect`, etc. to SVG including all the styles that was applied to this objects?

Appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric.js objects have a method called `toSVG()` for generating an SVG string. You can use it like this:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
console.log(obj.toSVG());
```